# Scala reflection to resolve generic trait from name at runtime

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I have two traits and their instance objects defined as following :

```
package reflection

trait Monoid[T] {
  def id: T
  def op(lhs: T, rhs: T): T
}

trait ADTHelper[T]{
  type V
  def create(value: V): T
  def get(adt: T): Any
}

case class Avg(avg: Double, n: Int)

object AvgMonoid extends Monoid[Avg] with ADTHelper[Avg]{
  override def id: Avg = Avg(0, 0)

  override def op(lhs: Avg, rhs: Avg): Avg =
    Avg( (lhs.avg * lhs.n + rhs.avg * rhs.n)/(lhs.n + rhs.n), lhs.n + rhs.n)

  override type V = Double
  override def create(value: Double): Avg = Avg(value, 1)
  override def get(adt: Avg): Any = adt.avg
}

object MinMonoid extends Monoid[Double] with ADTHelper[Double]{
  override def id: Double = Double.MaxValue

  override def op(lhs: Double, rhs: Double): Double = if(lhs < rhs) lhs else rhs

  override type V = Double

  override def create(value: Double): Double = value

  override def get(adt: Double): Any = adt
}
```

I want to get monoid instances at runtime from names. Forexample, if i say `"min"`, I want `MinMonoid` object, `"avg"` should give `AvgMonoid` object, etc. So i have following setup:

```
object Test extends App {

  val AGGREGATORS_NAME_DICT = Map(
    "avg" -> "reflection.AvgMonoid",
    "min" -> "reflection.MinMonoid",
    "max" -> "reflection.MaxMonoid"
  )
  val AGGREGATORS_ADT_DICT = Map(
    "avg" -> "reflection.Avg",
    "min" -> "scala.Double",
    "max" -> "scala.Double"
  )

  val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

  def stringToTypeTag[A](name: String): TypeTag[A] = {
    val tpe = mirror.staticClass(name).selfType
    TypeTag(mirror, new api.TypeCreator {
      def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
        if (m eq mirror) tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
    })
  }

  def resolve[T](fname: String): Option[Monoid[T] with ADTHelper[T]] = for {
    monoidName <- AGGREGATORS_NAME_DICT.get(fname)
    adtName <- AGGREGATORS_ADT_DICT.get(fname)
    tag <- Option{stringToTypeTag[T](adtName)}
    instance <- Option {
      mirror
        .reflectModule(mirror.staticModule(monoidName))
        .instance
        .asInstanceOf[Monoid[T] with ADTHelper[T]]
    }
  } yield instance
}
```

Now the problem is:
I can do:

```
println(resolve("min").get.op(1.0, 2.0))
```

but I can't do:

```
val monoid = resolve("min").get
println(monoid.op(1.0, 2.0))
```

because the type of `monoid` in later is `Monoid[Nothing] with ADTHelper[Nothing]`. I am unable to resolve the underlying type `T` of `trait Monoid[T]` and `trait ADTHelper[T]` using the `resolve` method I have come up with. How can I modify the `resolve` function so that it resolves the traits with Underlying Type `T` ???

I know If I call using `resolve[Double](...)`, it will work, But I want this to resolve in runtime from the `AGGREGATORS_ADT_DICT` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolving `T` at runtime is impossible, because there *is* no `T` to resolve then! When you write `resolve("min")`, the compiler *has* to determine its type argument during compilation. And because the arguments don't tell it anything about `T`, and the context doesn't provide an expected type (e.g. `val monoid: Monoid[Double] = resolve("min")`, it's going to infer `Nothing`. And note that `resolve`'s code doesn't matter at all here, only its type signature.

You could make `resolve` a macro, thus determining `T` at the runtime of the macro, i.e. the compile-time of the program using this macro. But this would only work for the case you know the name at compile-time (e.g. it's a literal string).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, it's due to erasure in JVM, right? Any alternative approach you can suggest for accomplishing this?

Comment: Actually, I want to get those Maps from config file. I'm not sure if using macros will work, because, I want these traits to be extensible later (outside of this codebase) and make this work just be providing the Maps in config file, and providing objects that extends these traits.

Comment: Even if JVM didn't erase types, the type arguments still would need to be determined at compile-time for type-checking.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I got what you mean to say.